# Web application Listview question

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview

In a list view in C# how can I make all the fields in a column editable at once? Right now I have the standard edit button which allows me to update just one line at a time. I want the end user to be able to click a button and allow then to edit the column in its entirety.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rebind the ListView with all TextBoxes when the user clicks edit.

You would have to manually track if you're in edit mode or not and on postback loop through all the rows retrieving the values from the textboxes and store them.

There is no built-in functionallity for what you're trying to do but it's possible.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/315349/how-do-i-edit-all-rows-in-an-asp-net-listview-control-at-the-same-time