# Listview updates database

Tags: asp.net, listview

This is my first post on stack overflow. I am quite new to aspnet development but am learning fast!
I am struggling to use the list view functionality. I want to create a list view that includes a checkbox. The list view is populated from a data table and the checkbox is used to denote attendance. So the same principle as a class register. When the user clicks on the checkbox, I want to update the database table.

I can create the list box. But I cannot work out the code behind to update the database. Can someone please help me with this. I am very grateful.

Here is my list box code...

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1"></asp:ListView>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:TestConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [ID], [LastName], [FirstName], [Present] FROM [Test1]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Hello Napoli, apologies for not knowing the rules. Where I need help is that I don't know how to do this! I can use VS debug and am learning that too. Thanks for the link to a great article. Definitely the way forward. As of yesterday I am fully using it!!

Comment: I have used the code on this link...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/315349/how-do-i-edit-all-rows-in-an-asp-net-listview-control-at-the-same-time  but I don't know how to get the button to update the db. eg. protected void cmdSave_Click ( object sender, EventArgs e )
{
    foreach ( ListViewItem item in lvwDepartments.Items )
    {
        if ( item.ItemType == ListViewItemType.DataItem )
        {
            TextBox txtDepartmentName = ( TextBox ) item.FindControl( "txtDepartmentName" );

            // Process changed data here...
        }
    }
}